# Потоки в Node.JS

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Есть бот, который выполняет код пользователя, если ввести "/dev код":

```
const bot_kernel = require('node-vk-bot-api');

const bot = new bot_kernel({
    token: "this is some vk api token"
});

bot.command(['/DEV', '='], (ctx) => {
    a = "some Node.JS code...";
    ctx.reply(`${a}`); return; // отправит сообщение с результатом
});


bot.startPolling(() => {
    console.log('Started Bot!'); // ждет сообщений от пользователя
});
```

Но если кто-то запускает, например, цикл, то бот не отвечает уже другим, пока не вернется результат. **Как можно сделать так, чтобы после запуска одного кода, бот продолжал слушать и обрабатывать сообщения?**

Comment: Не запускайте цикл.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я так думаю, вам надо использовать `async` функцию. В JS нет потоков. Настоятельно рекомендую почитать про `event loop`.

```js
bot.command(['/DEV', '='], async (ctx) => {
    a = "some Node.JS code...";
    ctx.reply(`${a}`); return; // отправит сообщение с результатом
});
```